# How to unbind and rebind?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, key-bindings

When working with tables, I noticed that `org-table-insert-row` is not bound to any keybinding.
I would like to bind it to `M-S-<down>`, but this key binding is currently associated with

```
<M-S-down> runs the command move-text-down, which is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function in
‘move-text-20170909.330/move-text.el’.

It is bound to <M-S-down>, <C-S-down>, <menu-bar> <Prelude> <Editing> <Move down>.
```

`move-text-down` has so many bindings!
In any case, how to tell my `init.el` to unbind the existing binding to `move-text-down`?
I have at the moment:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<M-S-down>") 'org-table-insert-row)  ;
```

But it is not working.

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate: you need to bind it in the `org-mode-map`, *not* the global map.

Comment: `M-S-<down>`  does different things in different contexts. In particular, in a table, it does `org-table-insert-row`. Visit an Org mode file and check the `Table/Row` menu.

Comment: Thanks, guys. Could you explain me how to specifically bind it to org-mode-map? Pretty helpless with IT things. In my prelude it is not bound to org-table-insert-row (I have tested it in tables and checked with C-h k).

Comment: `(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-down>") 'org-table-insert-row)`

Comment: By default, `<M-S-down>` is bound in the `org-mode-map` to the command `org-shiftmetadown`. This command looks at the current context and calls different functions, depending on that context. E.g in a table, it calls `org-table-insert-row`. You should not have to do anything to get that functionaltiy.

Comment: Thanks, @Drew However, it won't work. There must be something overseeing this setting. 
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "<M-S-down>") 'org-table-insert-row) won't fix this. :(

Comment: @NickD It may be that it is a Prelude setting?

Comment: No idea: I don't use Prelude.